# Location Accuracy in Browser with navigation.geolocation

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, safari, gps, geolocation

I am creating a browser app where, one of the pieces of functionality, is that the user is placed on a map, and then the surrounding area is searched for nearby "things." It is important (and a requirement) that I am as accurate as possible since the nearby location makes a big difference to what is shown to the user.

In order to place the person on the map, I wrote the below code (there is a bit more, but I'm leaving that part out). But, in every case, I am seeing the accuracy range from right on top of my location, to up to a few hundred meters away. There doesn't seem to be any rhyme or reason as to why.

I am outside when I am measuring. I am disconnected from any WiFi (but my WiFi is enabled). I am testing iOS devices on Safari and Chrome, and I am testing Android devices on Chrome. The results are similar across all devices.

One thing I have noticed is that I see that the phones are making requests for location. I see the GPS symbol show up (briefly) on my Android devices. I can see that Safari and Chrome have made recent location requests in the Apple Location Settings. In addition, when I navigate the user to the location (which breaks out into apps like Google Maps or Apple Maps), the location is very accurate and found immediately.

Am I doing something wrong here? Is there something I can do to increase accuracy?

```
    // Attempt to get low-accuracy location if high cannot be retrieved.
    function handleLocationError_high(error) {
        if(error.code == error.TIMEOUT) {
            // Attempt low accuracy if a timeout occurs.
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
                locationSuccessCallback,
                handleLocationError_low,
                {timeout: 10000, maximumAge: 0, enableHighAccuracy: false});
        } else {
            handleLocationError_low(error);
        }
    }

    // Handle the error if location cannot be retrieved at all.
    function handleLocationError_low(error) {
        console.log('No location found!');
    }

    // Geolocation callback if there is success in getting the golocation (high or low accuracy).
    function locationSuccessCallback(position) {
        var pos = {
            lat: position.coords.latitude,
            lng: position.coords.longitude
        };
        // ...place the user on the map.
    }

    // Try HTML5 geolocation.
    // Test for support of geolocation. If it is not supported, error.
    // Next, attempt to get high accuracy (GPS) position. If that times out, get the low accuracy position.
    if(!navigator.geolocation) {
        handleLocationError_low();
        return;
    }
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
        locationSuccessCallback, 
        handleLocationError_high,
        {timeout: 5000, maximumAge: 0, enableHighAccuracy: true});
```